# How do I manage to let Grails handle a wide variety of Date inputs?

Tags: date, datetime, grails

I would like Grails to handle a variety of date inputs in the same input section/for the same database field.

The <g:datePicker> is great and all, but it handles everything on the server side, and what I see in my view-HTML does not match the output in the browser. Additionally: I can have only one <g:datePicker>, as far as I know, for the same database field. I can set this Picker to a specific precision ("month", for example), and it works great. But here comes the catch:

I want the user to be able to insert all these dates in the single input section, and they should all be valid:

- just the year
- date and year
- complete date without time
- complete date with time

and then let Grails handle the rest.

- If somebody selects only the year, e. g. "2000" -> "2000-01-01 00:00:00" should be written to the database,
- if somebody selects "May" "2000" -> "2000-05-01 00:00:00" should be written to the database,
- if somebody selects "3" "May" "2000" -> "2000-05-03 00:00:00" should be written to the database,
- or somebody can enter a complete date with time, like usual.

What is the best way to handle this issue?

Thank you all very much!

PS: I tried using the g:datePicker reactively, but of course this didn't work. Like described above, what I see in my HTML is not what I got in the browser.

Comment: The version with "day, month, and year", works out of the box, since I don't have to enter a time. Sorry for adding this here. I really need to manage only the "year" and "year and month" case.